# I can't understand why is this string concatenation working

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand a little bit more about C strings and how they works under the hood. I have 3 strings declared, 53, 11, and 33 bytes long respectively (including the `\0` at the end of each one). Then I concatenate them to a new string, `to_be_used`, which I manually set to **33 bytes** long (I found this value by trial and error until the result string get strange if this value is less then 33). Se the code below:

```
void generate_random_password(int password_lenght, int has_special_characters)
{
    const char letters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    const char digits[] = "0123456789";
    const char special_characters[] = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~";

    char random_password[password_lenght + 1];

    if(has_special_characters == 1)
    {
        char to_be_used[33];

        strcat(to_be_used, letters);
        strcat(to_be_used, digits);
        strcat(to_be_used, special_characters);

        printf("%s\n", to_be_used);
        printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", sizeof(letters), sizeof(digits), sizeof(special_characters), sizeof(to_be_used));
    }
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
53
11
33
33
```

Each parameter for this function call is set as 17 for the first one and 1 for the last one.

The result string from the `strcat()` calls is exactly what I expected. My question is: why does this code compile even when the sum of the sizes of the 3 strings is 94 (excluding the \0 from end of each string) and I set the result string to 33?

I hope I explained it right.

Please, if someone knows a better way to write this code (of course that is some), answer me how can this code be better, like, using pointer to char, malloc(), or something else. Thanks!

PS: This function is not complete yet.
PS2: I'm a beginner in C programming.

Comment: When you declare `char to_be_used[33];` the compiler will reserve some minimum storage size that guarantees at least `33` characters can be stored, even though the minimum storage size reserved may actually be `64` or `128` bytes. So, while the compiler may have provided some larger amount of storage to satisfy page-size or alignment requirements, you are only allowed to access `33` of those bytes because there is no guarantee anything beyond that will exist. When your `strcat` results in writing beyond the 33rd byte you invoke *Undefined Behavior* in your code -- all bets are off.

Comment: *"My question is: why does this code compile even when the sum of the sizes of the 3 strings is 94 (excluding the \0 from end of each string) and I set the result string to 33?"* -- Answer: C doesn't come with training-wheels. That is what makes C so blistering fast, but also what places the absolute responsibility on you -- the programmer -- to ensure your code does not violate the promises you have made to the compiler. When you request 33-bytes, the compiler will give you 33-bytes and guarantee your access to them. If you then use 34-bytes -- it's not the compiler's fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to an array past the bounds is undefined behavior, which means anything can happen. It's like playing Russian roulette. In this particular program, you happened to luck out and have it overwrite some relatively-unimportant piece of memory (probably `random_password`), so it seemed like it worked. Next time you might not be so lucky.

Answer (score 0):

It is your responsibility to allocate enough memory.

The compiler is not obliged to catch you when you break a contract. The contract on `strcat` is that the target array is large enough to hold the result. If you do not honour it, the behaviour is undefined. See [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) for more info.

By the way, you cannot `strcat` an uninitialised string.

```
    char to_be_used[33];
    strcat(to_be_used, letters); // <- uninitialised, another instance of undefined behaviour
```

Comment: Now I initialized it with:
char to_be_used[33] = "";
Got the same result, it works

Comment: @maverick1013 Please read the answer again, paying attention this time. Please also read the other answer.